# How to deploy the nextjs 13 application on a Windows PC to run on a local network

Tags: docker, next.js, local

I have a Next JS 13 application with a mysql database, and I want to deploy the final product on a Windows machine so that it runs in a small local network of only 10 people.

How do I do this?

Comment: `exit code: 1` pretty much just means "it didn't work"; is there more to that error message?  Do you actually need to install this OS package; if you do, would it be easier to switch to a Debian-based image that already includes GNU libc?